# Falha em segmento de URL

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a problem in the URL of my application, do I have a product that forms a segment that URL and the middle name of the product has a '/' character. He wanted to know how I can fix this because if I replace that character on the other I lose the reference of this product, wanted to see if I have any way to treat this as as I am beginner'm having some difficulty. An example URL so it's like using date in the URL as below:

**mywebsite/testing/12/24/2014**

Comment: you should use parameter as different separator like  12-24-2014 or when receive  you should get each one  month,day,year separately.

Comment: but as described, the date was just an example of the error I'm having. My problem is not dated, but with a product of my application in the middle of the name of this product contains the slash character, as if I were to put as URL segment a product with the name "iron rod 3/4 ". How can I treat it?

Comment: Use replace before and after posting .

Comment: There is no other way other than using the replace it?

Answer (score 0):

I think there is one, using [rawurlencode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rawurlencode.php) for your product name.

```
<?php
echo '<a href="http://mywebsite/products/' . rawurlencode('iron rod 3/4') . '">';
?>
```